# how to add custom action in manage products and perform that action? in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, php-5.4

How to add custom action in manage catagories and perform that action? in magento

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the event `adminhtml_catalog_product_grid_prepare_massaction` to add a new item similar to the ones that already exist. For example take a look at the `delete` item:

```
$this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('delete', array(
         'label'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Delete'),
         'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/*/massDelete'),
         'confirm' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Are you sure?')
    ));
```

The `url` represents the url where the form is submitted. Create your own admin controller, send the for to it and process the data you receive in it.